# jQuery .post() function doesn't work with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post, xampp

Since a while I'm having trouble making the post function work. I've tried everything I found on the internet but nothing seems to help.
These are my files:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sendButton").click(function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      var text = document.getElementById("xd").value;
      $.post("reg_send.php",
      {
          name: text
        },
        function(data){
          $("#xd").html(data);
        });
        $("#xd").html("Trying");
    });
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <form style="width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;">
    <p id="xd">TextHere</p>
    <button type="button" class="mx-auto btn btn-danger" id="sendButton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1">Enviar</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And the reg_send.php file:

```
<?php
echo "working";
?>
```

But it just doesn't work, and I can't figure out why. I've tried using this too but nothing:

```
  <script>
    function send(){
     $.post('reg_send',{},
      function(data){
        $("#Titulo").html("Xd");
      });

      }
  </script>
```

And calling send() on the onClick of the button. I want to use thin o a XAMPP server, also tried setting it up there and nothing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, You are using the slim version of jQuery, which doesn't have **$.post()** function of AJAX.

Use the complete build, available here http://jquery.com/download/, such as:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jquery slim does not provides support to ajax methods in order to use ajax within jquery you need to use jquery.min.js or jquery.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sendButton").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'reg_data.php', 
                data: 'Hello'
            })
</script>
```